# Wishlist icon color not changing UseState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Intially based on isinwishlist it sets heartfilled or heartunfilled.
But suppose If It was heartfilled, but after on click I am setting iconColor value to false (i.e !iconcolor). But it doesn't changes, icon still remains same.
Could you please check what I am doing wrong.  handleRemove and handleAddToWishlist working fine.

```
const  ProductDetails = ({ product, isInWishlist}) => {


const [iconColor, setIconColor] = useState(isInWishlist);  //check  if present in wishlist

return (  <div  >
                  {iconColor ? (   
                    <HeartFilled
                      
                      onClick={() => {
                         
                        setIconColor(false);             //change iconcolor to false
                        handleRemove(product._id);       //remove it from backend
                      }}
                     
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <HeartOutlined
                      
                      onClick={() => {
                        
                          setIconColor(!iconColor);
                          handleAddToWishlist(product._id);
                         
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                  )}

                 
                </div>
              </div>
);
}
```

Comment: How do you receive the `isinwishlist` state? (and also please fix it - camelCase )

Comment: updated the code, it is passed as props it check whether this product is in wishlist on or not, through api.

Comment: okay, please don't mix `props` and `state`
aside from this make the Icon pure component and just pass what you will need to change after the api call or before and change it dynamically.
This may not fix the issue but the code will be better.
<icon filled={boolean} onClick={callApi & change filled boolean} />

Comment: ok thanks, but why it's not changing icon even I have changed iconcolor value after onclick  setIconColor(!iconColor).

Comment: 100% sure that the value is changing?

Comment: Yes that's the issue its not setting value in iconcolor through useState(isInWishlist). But isInWishlist value is coming true, but iconcolor still stows false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255880/discussion-between-zhivko-nikolov-and-singh-ekas).